# UserControl and Canvas - Vector Animation

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, wpf-controls

I want to do a usercontrol, that show and hide (visible & collapsed) a vector object in my project. For that a got a canvas element in my grid.

And truing to make an animation of 2 object Layer1 and Layer2.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="ProgressAnimation" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Layer1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="Visible"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>

            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Layer2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="Visible"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Next I make a trigger :

```
 <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ProgressAnimationBeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource ProgressAnimation}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>
```

And insert my element in to Grid :

```
<Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="Layer1" Margin="74,112,78,40" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Path Data="########" Fill="#FF00FF99" Height="148.219" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="147.623"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas x:Name="Layer2" Margin="74,113,79,40" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Path Data="########" Fill="#FF00FF99" Height="147.36" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="147.243"/>
        </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

In MainForm insert that code to XAML :

```
<Grid>
    <control:LoadingForm HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Height="298" Width="304"/>
</Grid>
```

And that not work properly - got that error :

```
Error   1   The animation(s) applied to the 'Visibility' property calculate a current value of 'Visible', which is not a valid value for the property.  J:\Projects\LoadingPj\LoadingPj\MainWindow.xaml 1   2   LoadingPj
```

Who can help me to understand my problem?
Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to specify `Visibility.Visible` value explicitly:

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
```

Seems like it was treated as a string value.